# « Même si » ou « même avec »

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, reformulation

Tu penses que la salle de bain de ton bar est conforme même s’il y a trois marches à enjamber

Tu penses que la salle de bain de ton bar est réglementaire même avec trois marches à monter.

Tu penses que la salle de bain de ton bar est réglementaire aux yeux de la municipalité en dépit des trois marches à enjamber ?
D’autres refontes plus heureuses à suggérer ?

Comment: _Tu penses que la salle de bain de ton bar est réglementaire malgré les trois marches à enjamber ?_ > "en dépit de" me semble trop littéraire dans le contexte.

Comment: salle de bain dans un bar, ou des toilettes ou sanitaires? :)

Comment: :) Des toilettes!!

Comment: Mais on l’occurrence la salle des toilettes contient une douche vu que le local a déjà servi de loft auparavant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tu cuides que les lieux d'aisance de ton estaminet siéent aux mandements municipaux nonobstant les trois marches à gravir pour les rejoindre ?

Answer (score 0):

Bien qu’il y ait trois marches à enjamber.